# How to filter by object property in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom filter in AngularJS that will filter a list of objects by the values of a specific property. In this case, I want to filter by the "polarity" property(possible values of "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative").

Here is my working code without the filter:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="total">
    <h2 id="totalTitle"></h2>
    <div>{{tweets.length}}</div>
    <div id="totalPos">{{tweets.length|posFilter}}</div>
    <div id="totalNeut">{{tweets.length|neutFilter}}</div>
    <div id="totalNeg">{{tweets.length|negFilter}}</div>
</div>
```

**Here is the "$scope.tweets" array in JSON format:**

```
{{created_at: "Date", text: "tweet text", user:{name: "user name", screen_name: "user       screen name", profile_image_url: "profile pic"}, retweet_count: "retweet count", polarity: "Positive"},
 {created_at: "Date", text: "tweet text", user:{name: "user name", screen_name: "user screen name", profile_image_url: "profile pic"}, retweet_count: "retweet count", polarity: "Positive"},
 {created_at: "Date", text: "tweet text", user:{name: "user name", screen_name: "user screen name", profile_image_url: "profile pic"}, retweet_count: "retweet count", polarity: "Positive"}}
```

**The best filter I could come up with as follows:**

```
myAppModule.filter('posFilter', function(){
return function(tweets){
    var polarity;
    var posFilterArray = [];
    angular.forEach(tweets, function(tweet){
        polarity = tweet.polarity;
        console.log(polarity);
        if(polarity==='Positive'){
              posFilterArray.push(tweet);
        }
        //console.log(polarity);
    });
    return posFilterArray;
};
});
```

This method returns an empty array. And nothing is printed from the "console.log(polarity)" statement. It seems like I am not inserting the correct parameters to access the object property of "polarity."

Any ideas? Your response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice question, but code could be reduced, big part of it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You simply have to use the `filter` filter (see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)) :

```html
<div id="totalPos">{{(tweets | filter:{polarity:'Positive'}).length}}</div>
<div id="totalNeut">{{(tweets | filter:{polarity:'Neutral'}).length}}</div>
<div id="totalNeg">{{(tweets | filter:{polarity:'Negative'}).length}}</div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAFjL/)</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to filter the item list by passing a custom filter to an ng-click event outside of the ng-repeat statement? In this case, I want to place three "polarity" buttons above the results that filter based on the rating.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If you want to choose the polarity to filter, you can pass a scope variable instead of a plain text : ```filter:{polarity:polarityToFilter}``` where ```$scope.polarityToFilter``` is filled by a click on one of the three buttons. Is this what you are trying to do ?

Comment: That seems like it could work. However, my app also needs to be able to delete individual list items.

Comment: The problem with filtering is that a new array is created every time a filter is applied which breaks the tie between a filtered item and its original index in the unfiltered array. Is there a way to maintain the tie or is ng-hide my only option? Here's a tutorial for an alternative to filtering by using ng-hide:                                     http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-Filter-vs-ngHide-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS.htm

Comment: [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) exposes an `$index` propertie on the local scope that you can also use.

Comment: I was able to filter using ng-hide. My current delete method looks like this:                                                                 $scope.delete = function (idx) {
            $scope.tweets.splice(idx, 1);                           While using a regular filter, this method does not delete the current list item while using the filter. For instance, if I filter the array, and delete an item at index 0 of the new filtered array, then the item at index 0 of the unfiltered array is removed. This problem is fixed with the ng-hide method.

Comment: In my case `tweets` was an array, so filter returned an array with one element. I had to use `(tweets | filter:{polarity:'Positive'})[0].length`.

Answer (score 27):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) has the complete answer. Anyway this is how it is done:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filterValue">
<li ng-repeat="i in data | filter:{age:filterValue}:true"> {{i | json }}</li>
```

will filter only `age` in `data` array and `true` is for exact match.

For deep filtering,

```
<li ng-repeat="i in data | filter:{$:filterValue}:true"> {{i}}</li>
```

The `$` is a special property for deep filter and the `true` is for exact match like above.

Comment: Simple and clean.

Comment: Is this filter inbuilt or need to be written in  both Angular & AngularJS?

Answer (score 23):

You could also do this to make it more dynamic.

```
<input name="filterByPolarity" data-ng-model="text.polarity"/>
```

Then you ng-repeat will look like this

```
<div class="tweet" data-ng-repeat="tweet in tweets | filter:text"></div>
```

This filter will of course only be used to filter by polarity

Answer (score 5):

We have Collection as below:

[image]

**Syntax:**

```
{{(Collection/array/list | filter:{Value : (object value)})[0].KeyName}}
```

**Example:**

```
{{(Collectionstatus | filter:{Value:dt.Status})[0].KeyName}}
```

***-OR-***

**Syntax:**

```
ng-bind="(input | filter)"
```

**Example:**

```
ng-bind="(Collectionstatus | filter:{Value:dt.Status})[0].KeyName"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. its working for me **'name'** is a property in arr.

```
repeat="item in (tagWordOptions | filter:{ name: $select.search } ) track by $index
```