# Get specific object by id from array of objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I have a JSON file containing some data I d like to access on my AngularJS website. Now what I want is to get only one object from the array. So I d like for example Item with id 1.

The data looks like this:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Beispiel"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sample"
    }
] }
```

I'd like to load the data with AngularJS $http functionality like this:

`$http.get("data/SampleData.json");`

which is working. But how can I now get a specific data object (by id) from the array I get from `$http.get` ?

Comment: Have you given it a go yourself? If so, can we see what you came up with?

Comment: Well I have no idea which way would be the best using AngularJS. What I dont like is to iterate over the array and do a equals on the id. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: You should rely on underscorejs or similar libraries for such processing. AngularJS is MVVM framework and may not have api for this.

Comment: @marcbaur - you have to iterate the array. Even if you use underscore, or something similar, it's functions, behind the scenes, are just iterating.

Comment: please add angular code for this

Comment: looks like it's time to change the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to iterate over the array. Obviously if you are sure that the results are ordered by id you can do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: ... I really hope after reading this answer people don't think it's a good idea to sort an array then do a binary search. Binary search is *clever*, sure, but *only* if the array is already sorted, and in reality is: 1. easy to poorly implement, 2. Harder to read if poorly implemented.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if the downvoters could motivate their decision.

Comment: By default javascript Array type has method find(). The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Answer (score 249):

**Using ES6 solution**

For those still reading this answer, if you are using ES6 the `find` method was added in arrays. So assuming the same collection, the solution'd be:

```
const foo = { "results": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Beispiel"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sample"
    }
] };
foo.results.find(item => item.id === 2)
```

I'd totally go for this solution now, as is less tied to angular or any other framework. Pure Javascript.

**Angular solution (old solution)**

I aimed to solve this problem by doing the following:

```
$filter('filter')(foo.results, {id: 1})[0];
```

A use case example:

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    var foo = { "results": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Beispiel"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Sample"
        }
    ] };

    // We filter the array by id, the result is an array
    // so we select the element 0

    single_object = $filter('filter')(foo.results, function (d) {return d.id === 2;})[0];

    // If you want to see the result, just check the log
    console.log(single_object);
}]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5E7FYqNNqDuqFBlyDqRh?p=preview

Comment: Actually, I'd think it does! After fetching the array, you can use the $filter function to filter out the item with the correct id.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had the same question in my head and this answer is the only one that uses existing AngularJS and isn' reinventing the wheel. And yes, it is working.

Comment: +1 for this being the accepted answer. Best solution using angular libraries.

Comment: A related topic I found useful for running the filter in an expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs

Comment: Plunker with filter in an expression: http://plnkr.co/edit/yc0uZejGqWTcUVKvI7Tq?p=preview

Comment: Be aware that filters find by case insensitive substrings by default. So (foo.results, {id: 2}) returns [{id: 12}, {id: 2}], {id:222}]    but (foo.results, function (d) {return d.id === 2;}) returns [{id: 2}]

Comment: Should just do something like this: var object_by_id = $filter('filter')(foo.results, {id: 2 })[0]; - See my answer below.

Comment: how performant is angular filter compared to underscore solutions

Comment: What about filtering with two `id`s? I mean the second `id` comes from a nested data of the `json`.

Comment: what is the runtime of this?

Answer (score 26):

For anyone looking at this old post, this is the easiest way to do it currently. It only requires an AngularJS `$filter`. Its like Willemoes answer, but shorter and easier to understand.

```
{ 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Beispiel"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Sample"
        }
    ] 
}

var object_by_id = $filter('filter')(foo.results, {id: 2 })[0];
// Returns { id: 2, name: "Beispiel" }
```

---

> **WARNING**
>
> As @mpgn says, this **doesn't work properly**. This will catch more results. **Example:** *when you search 3 this will catch 23 too*

Comment: also catch id: 24 12 222 2002 etc

Comment: I would think that the `[0]` would cause it to return the first result it finds from the collection, so it would only work if your collection is sorted and the object you're looking for is the first it finds during its iteration. Eg. if there's a id:12 that comes before id: 2, it would return id: 12.

Answer (score 25):

personally i use underscore for this kind of stuff... so

```
a = _.find(results,function(rw){ return rw.id == 2 });
```

then "a" would be the row that you wanted of your array where the id was equal to 2

Comment: I **really love** underscore, but, _does it worse having another JavaScript library?_

Comment: Note that `find` can potentially return multiple objects. Since we only want one, we can use `findWhere` which only returns the first occurrence (which we know is the only occurrence), e.g. `a = _.findWhere(results, {id: 2})`.

Answer (score 17):

I just want to add something to [Willemoes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24393892/957286).
The same code written directly inside the HTML will look like this:

```
{{(FooController.results | filter : {id: 1})[0].name }}
```

Assuming that "results" is a variable of your FooController and you want to display the "name" property of the filtered item.

Comment: @Ena-How to check result of filter is not null or undefined ?

Comment: I used this HTML variant because I was sure a result existed. I tried and if there is no result the console does not give any error, it simply leaves the text blank. If you need to do some logic if no result is found then I think the best way to go is Willemoes answer (js code inside controller). In that example, you should then check in HTML if single_object variable is null or undefined.

Comment: {{(FooController.results | filter : {id: 1})[0].name }: true} - if somebody's looking for an exact match

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ng-repeat` and pick data only if data matches what you are looking for using `ng-show`
for example:

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in res.results" ng-show="data.id==1">
     {{data.name}}
 </div>
```

Comment: If your array has more than a trivial number of items, this will create a lot of unnecessary scopes which may slow down your application.

Answer (score 9):

You can just loop over your array:

```
var doc = { /* your json */ };

function getById(arr, id) {
    for (var d = 0, len = arr.length; d < len; d += 1) {
        if (arr[d].id === id) {
            return arr[d];
        }
    }
}

var doc_id_2 = getById(doc.results, 2);
```

If you don't want to write this messy loops, you can consider using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) (example in the latter):

```
var doc_id_2 = _.filter(doc.results, {id: 2})[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want the list of items like city on the basis of state id then use

```
var state_Id = 5;
var items = ($filter('filter')(citylist, {stateId: state_Id }));
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately (unless I'm mistaken), I think you need to iterate over the results object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1){
    var result = results[i];
    if(result.id === id){
        return result;
    }
}
```

At least this way it will break out of the iteration as soon as it finds the correct matching id.

Comment: Why? Do you have anything to back that up?

Comment: Well, do you know what..? I just went off to re-read Javascript - the good parts to counter your argument and I _am_ wrong! For all this time I've been doing it wrong! It hasn't caused me any problems though... yet. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Why complicate the situation? this is simple write some function like this:

```
function findBySpecField(data, reqField, value, resField) {
    var container = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
        if (container[i][reqField] == value) {
            return(container[i][resField]);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Use Case:

```
var data=[{
            "id": 502100,
            "name": "Bərdə filialı"
        },
        {
            "id": 502122
            "name": "10 saylı filialı"
        },
        {
            "id": 503176
            "name": "5 sayli filialı"
        }]

console.log('Result is  '+findBySpecField(data,'id','502100','name'));
```

output:

```
Result is Bərdə filialı
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$scope.olkes = [{'id':11, 'name':'---Zəhmət olmasa seçim edin---'},
                {'id':15, 'name':'Türkyə'},
                {'id':45, 'name':'Azərbaycan'},
                {'id':60, 'name':'Rusya'},
                {'id':64, 'name':'Gürcüstan'},
                {'id':65, 'name':'Qazaxıstan'}];

<span>{{(olkes | filter: {id:45})[0].name}}</span>
```

output:   Azərbaycan

Answer (score 2):

If you can, design your JSON data structure by making use of the array indexes as IDs. You can even "normalize" your JSON arrays as long as you've no problem making use of the array indexes as "primary key" and "foreign key", something like RDBMS. As such, in future, you can even do something like this:

```
function getParentById(childID) {
var parentObject = parentArray[childArray[childID].parentID];
return parentObject;
}
```

This is the solution **"By Design"**. For your case, simply:

```
var nameToFind = results[idToQuery - 1].name;
```

Of course, if your ID format is something like **"XX-0001"** of which its array index is **0**, then you can either do some string manipulation to map the ID; or else nothing can be done about that except through the iteration approach.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am too late to answer but it's always better to show up rather than not showing up at all :). ES6 way to get it:

```
$http.get("data/SampleData.json").then(response => {
let id = 'xyz';
let item = response.data.results.find(result => result.id === id);
console.log(item); //your desired item
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to get (one) element from array by id:

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
    return element >= 15;
}

var integers = [12, 5, 8, 130, 160, 44];
integers.find(isBigEnough); // 130  only one element - first
```

you don't need to use filter() and catch first element xx.filter()[0] like in comments above

The same for objects in array

```
var foo = {
"results" : [{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Test"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Beispiel"
}, {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Sample"
}
]};

var secondElement = foo.results.find(function(item){
    return item.id == 2;
});

var json = JSON.stringify(secondElement);
console.log(json);
```

Of course if you have multiple id then use filter() method to get all objects.
Cheers

```js
function isBigEnough(element) {
    return element >= 15;
}

var integers = [12, 5, 8, 130, 160, 44];
integers.find(isBigEnough); // 130  only one element - first
```

```js
var foo = {
"results" : [{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Test"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Beispiel"
}, {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Sample"
}
]};

var secondElement = foo.results.find(function(item){
    return item.id == 2;
});

var json = JSON.stringify(secondElement);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    projectDetailsController.controller('ProjectDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('data/projects.json').success(function(data) {

        $scope.projects = data;
        console.log(data);

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.project = data[i];
        if($scope.project.name === $routeParams.projectName) {
            console.log('project-details',$scope.project);
        return $scope.project;
        }
        }

    });
});
```

Not sure if it's really good, but this was helpful for me.. 
I needed to use $scope to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

use $timeout and run a function to search in "results" array

```
app.controller("Search", function ($scope, $timeout) {
        var foo = { "results": [
          {
             "id": 12,
             "name": "Test"
          },
          {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "Beispiel"
          },
          {
             "id": 3,
            "name": "Sample"
          }
        ] };
        $timeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < foo.results.length; i++) {
                if (foo.results[i].id=== 2) {
                    $scope.name = foo.results[i].name;
                }
            }
        }, 10);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the results array using an angularjs filter like this:

var foundResultObject = getObjectFromResultsList(results, 1);

```
function getObjectFromResultsList(results, resultIdToRetrieve) {
        return $filter('filter')(results, { id: resultIdToRetrieve }, true)[0];
    }
```