# AngularJS: return an array inside Object

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to search inside JSON file by the _id, then only return the team_members array as you see below is an example of one object inside the file

```
    {
        "_id": "5769484bb3ef5c696c5686d0",
        "name": "XXXXX",
        "family": "XXXXX Products",
        "description": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "image": "http://localhost/img/proudct6.png",
        "__v": 8,
        "team_members": [{
            "_id": "57694567b3ef5c696c5686c2",
            "name": "XXXXXXX",
            "description": "team member",
            "image": "http://localhost/img/1.png",
            "mobile_number": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "specialty": "Developer",
            "summary": "only for test"
        }, {
            "_id": "57694567b3ef5c678c5686c6",
            "name": "XXXXXXX",
            "description": "team member",
            "image": "http://localhost/img/1.png",
            "mobile_number": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "specialty": "Developer",
            "summary": "only for test"
        }]
    }
```

and here my code:

```
this.getProductReferences = function(productId){
var dfd = $q.defer();
$http.get('database.json').success(function(database) {
  var product = _.find(database.products, function(product){ return product._id == productId; });
  var references =product.references;

  dfd.resolve(references);
});
return dfd.promise;
};
```

Comment: I dont think that is possible, try itrating over the array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590063/get-specific-json-object-by-id-from-json-array-in-angularjs

Comment: `_.find` works on array, not on object

Comment: database.products is an array of product objects ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 yes it's an array.

Comment: @PankajParkar actually the files content an array of products

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas i try but it's not work

Comment: Why are you returning the database, and not the already found product?
The search for the specific product _id should be done in the backend and only that product should be returned. And then you can access whatever property you want.

Comment: @Ted it's POC and i don't have time so i didn't make an api because i don't have the time to learn ionic and how to link with backend API. Also my the problem with view , because i don't only have team members i have 3 more array and the data will show to the client if and only if the client click the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mxit5EVX8aGIbz9OuXIY?p=preview). Since $http is promise based you can remove the dfd promise and return it directly.  Then handle the promise resolution from your calling func.

**Controller**

```
  var self = this;

  this.getProductReferences = function(productId) {
    return $http.get('database.json').success(function(database) {
      var product = _.find(database.products, function(product) {
        return product._id == productId;
      });
      return product.references;
    });
  };

  // this could be wrapped in a func that is called from your html
  this.getProductReferences("5769484bb3ef5c696c5686d0").then(function(result) {
    self.references = result.data.team_members;
  })
```

I chose to pass "5769484bb3ef5c696c5686d0" in as productId just for this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` service.

```
var object = $filter('filter')(database, {'_id': '5769484bb3ef5c696c5686d0'});
console.log(object.team_members) // here is your team members array
```

Comment: filter works on array, not sure if database is an array

Comment: He wrote that the example is an object inside the file. So I thought there should be many objects in an array in this json file.

Comment: in that case his own code should work as well (with some modifications maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, it's working with me know, 
some one write the answer and then delete and i don't know why but i try before and it's work..

```
  this.getProductReferences = function(productId) {
   return $http.get('database.json').success(function(database) {
     var product = _.find(database.products, function(product) {
       return product._id == productId;
     });
     return product.team_members;
   });
 };

 this.getProductReferences(productId).then(function(references) {
  $scope.references = references.data.team_members;
 });
```

Comment: I had deleted it since I needed to make a change but couldn't get to it right away.  I've undeleted it now.