# How do display a value from an array in a span

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently displaying the selected user on my page like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="u in vm.Users | filter:{UserId:vm.UserId} | limitTo : 1 ">    
    <span class="form-review">{{u.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

For some reason it is displaying the wrong user, and I can't figure out why.
The UserId is 7, and the value in vm.Users with UserId 7 is e.g. John but it is not displaying the correct name.

Is there another way I can find the user and display the user without using ng-repeat and filter?

I'm using angular 1.x

Comment: Which user is being displayed? Or is it blank?

Comment: User with an UserID of 17.   Not sure how the filter could get it wrong though?   It works for other users fine.  Maybe it has to do with 7 and 17?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Is my issue related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753608/4816175

Comment: Extremely likely. The highest voted answer appears to be a plausible solution as well.