# Angular - trouble using multiple filters on ng-repeat that has nested objects

Tags: angularjs

### Revised Question

I have an `ng-repeat` and I am trying to filter on a nested attribute. For example, how do you filter on `job:title`, which is nested, in the below set:

```
{
    "name":"Bob", 
    "job": {
        "title":"farmer",
        "difficulty":"medium"
    }
},
{
    "name":"Sue", 
    "job": {
        "title":"fisher",
        "difficulty":"hard"
    }
},
{
    "name":"Joe", 
    "job":{
        "title":"smith",
        "difficulty":"expert"
    }
}
```

### I made a solution in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/ch40a9kh/1/)

---

#### Original Question

I have an `ng-repeat` that uses nested values in each iteration.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilter ">
        <td>{{ item.user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.item_name.value }}</td>
    </tr>
```

I want multiple filters to act independently on each of those values. I can't seem to figure out the syntax:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Filter by User name" ng-model="myFilter.item.user.name"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Filter by Item name" ng-model="myFilter.item.item_name.value"/></td>
    </tr>
```

EDIT: Sample of the json object

```
{     "items":[  
     {  
        "item_id":{  
           "name":"item_id",
           "inputType":null,
           "alias":"item id",
           "required":null,
           "locked":true,
           "viewable":null,
           "groupNames":[],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":null,
           "value":4,
           "valueSet":null,
           "in":null
        },
        "user_id":{  
           "name":"user_id",
           "inputType":null,
           "alias":"user id",
           "required":null,
           "locked":true,
           "viewable":null,
           "groupNames":[],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":[  
              "in:"
           ],
           "value":2,
           "valueSet":null,
           "in":null
        },
        "item_name":{  
           "name":"item_name",
           "inputType":"String",
           "alias":"name",
           "required":true,
           "locked":null,
           "viewable":true,
           "groupNames":[],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":[  
              "string",
              "required"
           ],
           "value":"swd1",
           "valueSet":null,
           "in":null
        },
        "item_type":{  
           "name":"item_type",
           "inputType":null,
           "alias":"item type",
           "required":null,
           "locked":true,
           "viewable":null,
           "groupNames":[],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":null,
           "value":"sword",
           "valueSet":null,
           "in":null
        },
        "item_category":{  
           "name":"item_category",
           "inputType":null,
           "alias":"item category",
           "required":null,
           "locked":true,
           "viewable":true,
           "groupNames":[  
              "profile",
              "category"
           ],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":null,
           "value":"weapon",
           "valueSet":{  
              "values":[  
                 "weapon",
                 "protection"
              ],
              "selectLimit":1
           },
           "in":"weapon,protection,"
        },
        "item_weight":{  
           "step":null,
           "isInteger":null,
           "unitName":"lbs",
           "name":"item_weight",
           "inputType":"number",
           "alias":"weight",
           "required":true,
           "locked":null,
           "viewable":true,
           "groupNames":[  
              "profile"
           ],
           "priority":null,
           "validationRules":[  
              "numeric",
              "min:0",
              "max:99",
              "required"
           ],
           "value":1,
           "valueSet":null,
           "in":null
        },
        "user":{  
           "id":2,
           "name":"asdf",
           "email":"",
           "created_at":"2016-01-01 04:49:49",
           "updated_at":"2016-02-24 03:48:21"
        },
        "images":[],
        "reviews":[  
           {  
              "rev_id":5,
              "reviewable_type":"App\\Models\\ItemTaxonomy\\Item",
              "reviewable_id":4,
              "created_at":"2016-02-29 00:51:42",
              "updated_at":"2016-02-29 00:51:42"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

Comment: on what Values Multiple filter should act independent .. Can you please update your Aim of this post and sample object(optional). it seems bit unclear i have an idea about what you are asking but no sure 100%

Comment: you need to post the sample json structure

Comment: @N.V.Prasad sample json structure posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/ch40a9kh/1/) with help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs).

Breaking it down for dummies such as myself:

Each filter input element has its own `ng-model` value:

```
<tr>
    <td><input ng-model="nameSearch" type="text" placeholder="filter"/></td>
    <td><input ng-model="jobSearch" type="text" placeholder="filter"/></td>
</tr>
```

When applying the filter to the ng-repeat, the json of ther iteration object is the key (goes before `:`), and the ng-model term (defined above) is the value (goes after `:`):

`filter:{json.nested.item:nameSearch, different.nested.item:jobSearch}`

Applied:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{name:nameSearch,job.title:jobSearch}">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.job.title}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like below,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items |  filter:{name: search.user.name, itemName: search.item_name.value}">
    <td>{{ item.user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.item_name.value }}</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Filter by User name" ng-model="search.name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Filter by Item name" ng-model="search.itemName"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your sample object for `items` array ?

Comment: San Krish, please see edited post for sample json object. Thank you