# Angular filter not filtering correctly in version 1.3, is it better in version 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm currently using the built in angular filter "$filter" in my controller to filter a dropdown list of data but the filter isn't filtering the data correctly at all. It filters it but the filtered data doesn't match the text being typed. I was reading that there may be some issues with the state of filters not working correctly in 1.3 on objects and arrays? I'm wondering if this is a version issue or if I am doing something incorrectly in my code? I'm thinking about upgrading to 1.5 so I'm just curious if my problems would be solved in 1.5 or if I have syntax errors. Here is what I have:

DATA (this is the initial data being ng-repeated over and what is being filtered:

```
this.items = [
            { name: 'Jim', city: 'Minneapolis', state: 'MN', zip: 44332 },
            { name: 'Boe', city: 'Scottsdale', state: 'AZ', zip: 44332 },
            { name: 'Tom', city: 'S.F.', state: 'CA', zip: 11223 },
            { name: 'Joe', city: 'Dallas', state: 'TX', zip: 34543 },
            { name: 'Jon', city: 'L.A.', state: 'CA', zip: 56433 },
        ];
```

TEMPLATE:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputField" ng-change="ctrl.filterTextChangeLocal($event)" ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue" ng-click="ctrl.openDropdown($event)" />
```

The above input filters the list below:

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group" ng-if="!ctrl.ngDisabled">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems"
    ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
        {{row[ctrl.itemDisplayProperty]}}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item text-center" ng-show="ctrl.filteredItems.length <= 0">
        {{ctrl.noResultsMessage}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
     // filter the drodpown data
     //$event is being used to check for specific keypresses but doesn't matter here
     //ngModelValue is bound to ng-model inside the input

    public filterTextChangeLocal($event: ng.IAngularEvent) {
          this.filteredItems = this.$filter("filter")(this.items, this.ngModelValue);

    }
```

The result of above is a simple bootstrap ul dropdown list that would display a specified property on the objects in the list, here it would show the name property from the data shown above, but this data isn't correctly being filtered:

```
 <li>Jim</li>
 <li>Boe</li>
 <li>Tom</li>
 <li>Joe</li>
 <li>Jon</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your filter like as-

```
public filterTextChangeLocal($event: ng.IAngularEvent) {
          this.filteredItems = this.$filter("filter")(this.items, {'name':this.ngModelValue});

    }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be filtering correctly either. If I press "a" in the input, there should not be any names remaining in the dropdown as no names have am "a" in them

Comment: I take that back...this does work when the filtered property is the "name" or if I change it to "city" then it does filter correctly. How can I make that value dynamic. As this is a component and I'm not sure exactly what property in the objects above will be filtered. What's the best way to update or change that 'name' value based on what ever property is specified to be displayed..for example I use this.itemDisplayProperty = "name" or this.itemDisplayProperty = "city" to specify what property is displayed in the dropdown. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Angular filters work perfectly, the problem maybe reside in your implementation... Here is an example of your work:

> EDIT: if you want to filter an array based on a `property`, name in your case, you need to instruct the filter `item in items | filter:{key:value}`.
>   this is a reference: [How to filter by object property in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs)

```js
function TestCtrl($scope, data) {
  var vm = $scope;
  
  vm.items = data;
  vm.query = '';
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .value('data', [
    { name: 'Jim', city: 'Minneapolis', state: 'MN', zip: 44332 },
    { name: 'Boe', city: 'Scottsdale', state: 'AZ', zip: 44332 },
    { name: 'Tom', city: 'S.F.', state: 'CA', zip: 11223 },
    { name: 'Joe', city: 'Dallas', state: 'TX', zip: 34543 },
    { name: 'Jon', city: 'L.A.', state: 'CA', zip: 56433 },
  ])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'data', TestCtrl])
;
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.form-group {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="data" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{name: query} track by $index">
      
      <div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading" ng-bind="item.name"></h4>
    <p>
      <span ng-bind="item.city"></span> - 
      <span ng-bind="item.state"></span> - 
      <span ng-bind="item.zip"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
      
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be filtering correctly either..if I press "a" in the input I should only get names that have an "a" in them, which is none in this case

Comment: Because it filters on each property of your model.
The `a` character is present in other fields, not only in `name`. Have a look at my last edit.

Comment: yes ok that's what I realized. I have that functionality for the filtering of the whole object but was more stuck on the single property being displayed. I figured that part out though. Thanks a lot for the time.

Comment: one more question: how can I make the filter dynamic so that the user can filter based on what property in the object is displayed, for example if the user passes in item-display-property="city" then the dropdown list would show all the cities in the objects I have in my post. If they passed in "state" it would filter for state. But the user of the component specifies the data being passed in so they may have a property called "address" and if they pass in that I need the filter to fitler for address.

Comment: This works for static filtering:  this.filteredItems = this.$filter("filter")(this.items, {name : this.ngModelValue}); But when I try to make it dynamic by doing this: this.filteredItems = this.$filter("filter")(this.items, {this.itemDisplayProperty : this.ngModelValue});  it doesn't run because I can't use 'this' twice in the same object

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the time. I actually used the above answer for my solution and that worked for me but I your answers would work as well. I can't mark two. I upvoted your post though.