# how to use angularjs filter in filter particular feild

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

**Controller**

```
    app.controller('viewUsersController', function($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $modal) {
        $scope.cardsDisplayModeEnabled = true;
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/all?access_token=' + $cookieStore.get("access_token")).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.users = response.data;
        });

    $scope.filterStarWith = function(level) {
        var re = new RegExp('^' + "Supervisor", "i");
        return level.tfAccessLevel.match(re);
    };
})
```

**HTML**

```
 <select ng-controller="viewUsersController" ng-model="user.tfSupervisor.id" name="createSupervisor" id="createSupervisor" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="level in users | filter:filterStarWith()">{{level.userFirstName}}</option>
</select>


Table : user
Id         username          accesslevel          
1            John               Admin
2            Mark               Supervisor
3            Chady              Admin
```

I have to list in option whose access level is "Supervisor"

Thanks,

Comment: There is no specific question detail here or a concise problem statement. After you read [ask] update the question content with all relevant specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by access level directly within your ng-repeat.

```
ng-repeat="level in users | filter:{tfAccessLevel:'Supervisor'}"
```

Take a look at this answer: [How to filter by object property in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793751/how-to-filter-by-object-property-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this, using existing filter option

```
 <select ng-model="user.id" name="createSupervisor" id="createSupervisor" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="level in users  | filter: { accesslevel: 'Admin' }">{{level.userFirstName}}</option>
  </select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RoXFStAKrvCA6nXxBh60?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the entire data in your user object scope, you'll have access to both username and access level properties.

In this scenario, I don't see a reason to create a custom filter, as this can be handled by Angular's intelligent filter expression.

If you read the angular api, the filter can be using in HTML Template binding.

A filter in HTML template binding should be expression, propertyKey or comparator. In your case, you need to just inject your filter as

```
 <option ng-repeat="level in users | filter:filterStarWith "{{level.userFirstName}}</option>
```

or else

you can use something like this which is pretty straightforward.

```
<option ng-repeat="level in users | filter: {accesslevel: 'Supervisor' }"> {{level.userFirstName}}</option>
```